# Terminating OpenVPN in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, openvpn

For running OpenVPN in PowerShell in hidden mode, I am using:

```
Powershell -windowstyle hidden -Command " & 'C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe' --config 'C:\Users\Path\sms1.ovpn' --auth-user-pass 'C:\Users\Path\sms1.auth.txt' "
```

and for terminating it, having no other process with OpenVPN:

```
Powershell -Command "& Stop-Process -Name 'openvpn' -Force"
```

Is this the proper way to do it? I am very new with Powershell.

Comment: If that works for you, the why the query? Yet, if you are already in the PowerShell console/ISE/VSCode, there is no reason to shell out again, just run the Stop-Process cmdlet directly from whatever PowerShell terminal you are in.

Comment: I don't know if i should terminate it without forcing...

Comment: In most cases, you won't know if you'd need the force, until you try it without it. It does not hurt anything having it there though.